# RxJS proper way to merge 3 arrays into one, as an Observable

Tags: rxjs, observable

HI I have 3 Subjects ( they could be Observables )

```
 const arr1$ = new BehaviorSubject([])
 const arr2$ = new BehaviorSubject([])
 const arr3$ = new BehaviorSubject([])
```

let's say these subjects contain this data

```
arr1 = ['1','2'], 
arr2 = ['3','7'], 
arr3 = ['4']
```

I want to create an observable (mergedObservable) that combines the latest from these 3 observables, merges them into one array,  where the result is one array like this:
['1','2','3','7','4']

```
so that I can achieve this 
this.mergedObservable.subscribe( mergedArray => {
     console.log(mergedArray)
})
// ['1','2','3','7','4']
```

I am struggling with how to make this 'mergedObservable'. I have tried something like 
combineLatest(arr1$,arr2$,arr3$) , but I still need to 'chain' more functionality that will merge the 3.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`combineLatest` takes an optional `project` function that can be used to modify the combined value.

You can specify a `project` function that uses `Array.prototype.reduce` to flatten the arrays into a single array:

```js
const arr1$ = new Rx.BehaviorSubject(['1','2']);
const arr2$ = new Rx.BehaviorSubject(['3','7']);
const arr3$ = new Rx.BehaviorSubject(['4']);

Rx.Observable
  .combineLatest(
    arr1$, arr2$, arr3$,
    (...arrays) => arrays.reduce((acc, array) => [...acc, ...array], [])
  )
  .subscribe(value => console.log(value));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs@5/bundles/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Than you! it was the 'project' function that I wasn't understanding. much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

fake, fake1, api are different arrays or sources.

```
 combineLatest(fake, fake1, api)
    .pipe(
      map(([f,f1, apis])=>
       {
         return ([...f, ...f1, ...apis]);
       }
      )
   )
    .subscribe((data) => {
        console.log(data);
      });
```